# How many positive integral solutions for $\frac{xy}{x+y}= 2^4\cdot 3^5 \cdot 5^{4}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Consider the equation:

> $$\frac{xy}{x+y}= 2^4\cdot 3^5 \cdot 5^{4}$$

How many positive integral solutions are possible?

Comment: Here is a guide to [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: *Integral* or **integer** (I think the latter, but you tagged "abstract algebra"...)?

Comment: I hope $\frac{xy}{x+y}= 2^{4×3^{5×5^{4}}}$ this is what you intend

Comment: Thanks for reply. It is (2 raised to 4) x (3 raised to 5) x (5 raised to 4)

Comment: I mean 2^43^55^4

Comment: So you mean $2^4\times 3^5\times 5^4=2430000$?

Comment: Can you confirm that you just mean $2430000$ here?  If you do, I will edit your post accordingly.  Or, of course, you could edit it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

We can rearrange to give $x = \dfrac{yT}{y-T}$, where $T:=2^4\cdot 3^5\cdot 5^4$

To have positive solutions then, we clearly need $y > T$ and by symmetry $x>T$ also.

Define $v:=x-T, w:=y-T$, giving  $v = \dfrac{T^2+Tw}{w} -T \implies vw=T^2$

Then the number of solutions of $vw=T^2 = 2^8\cdot 3^{10}\cdot 5^{8}$ is simply $9\times 11\times 9 = 891$